# Curves in 3D, cartesian coordinates

Tags: curves

In cartesian coordinates, the curve $ \Psi(t) $ is defined by:
$$ \Psi (t)=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        5sin(t)cos({\frac 35t})\\
        4cos(t)\\
        5sin(t)sin({\frac 35t})\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
t  \in [-\frac{\Pi}{2},\frac{\Pi}{2}]
$$
Proof that the curve is always lying on an ellipsoid

$$
{\frac{(x^2+z^2)}{(A^2)}+\frac{(y^2)}{(B^2)}=1}
$$

and determine A and B.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=5sin(t)cos(\frac{3}{5} t)$, $y=4cos(t)$, $z=5sin(t)sin(\dfrac{3}{5}t)$, then:

$$\frac{(x^2+z^2)}{A^2}+\frac{(y^2)}{B^2}=\frac{25sin^2(t)cos^2(\frac{3}{5} t) + 25sin^2(t)sin^2(\dfrac{3}{5}t)}{A^2}+\frac{16cos^2(t)}{B^2}$$
$$=\frac{25sin^2(t)}{A^2}+\frac{16cos^2(t)}{B^2}$$

If $A=5$ and $B=4$ then

$$\frac{(x^2+z^2)}{A^2}+\frac{(y^2)}{B^2}=\frac{25sin^2(t)}{25}+\frac{16cos^2(t)}{16}=1$$